# CKEditor 4.5 beta to be officially delivered and supported

Tags: ckeditor

Is there any scheduled date for the CKEditor 4.5 beta to be officially delivered and supported.

We are very interested in the new drag and drop features.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor 4.5 should be officially realeased in June (provided no major issues arise, which should not really happen at this stage). You can also follow the [roadmap](https://dev.ckeditor.com/milestone/CKEditor%204.5.0) and read the [Weekly blog posts](http://ckeditor.com/blog/category/ckeditor-weekly) to learn more about our progess.